# unique constraint with a composite key

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following situation with a 'bad old' legacy db:

```
class FktDef {
    static belongsTo = [fktArt: FktArt] // FktArt has a composite primary key
    String fktBez

    static mapping = {
        column {
            fktArt {
                column name: 'fkt_art'
                column name: 'fkt_art_lfd'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it works so far...

But now I have the specification to have a unique constraint over [fktArt and fktBez]

if I define the following:

```
static constraints = {
    fktArt: unique: ['fktBez']
}
```

I get 2 constraints, one with [fkt_bez , fkt_art] and the other one with [fkt_bez , fkt_art_lfd] but my target should be a constraint over [fkt_bez, fkt_art , fkt_art_lfd]

Is there a way to achieve the specification? I tried several things but all throws a db-error...

I additionally tried:

```
fktArt: unique: ['fktArt', 'fktBez'] ...
fktArt: unique: ['fktArt.fktArt', 'fktArt.fktArtLfd', 'fktBez'] ...
fktBez: unique: ['fktArt'] etc.
```

but nothing works so far...